# Unify rotation direction on f-curve

Tags: animation, rigging, fcurves

I have used the bake action operator on a rig. Unfortunately if the rotations are too and fast the direction of rotation is getting the opposite direction. Do you have any idea, how to easily fix this?

Here you can see the current f curve in yellow and the desired one in red.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this coding solution:

```
import bpy
import math

def fcurve_point_postpro(fcurve):
  previous_value = 0
  for pnt in fcurve.keyframe_points:
    while pnt.co[1] <= previous_value:
      pnt.co[1] += 2 * math.pi
    previous_value = pnt.co[1]

def fcurve_postpro():
  for bpy_object in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    obj_fcurves = bpy_object.animation_data.action.fcurves
    x_fcurve = obj_fcurves.find('rotation_euler', index=0)
    fcurve_point_postpro(x_fcurve)

fcurve_postpro()
```